# WPF 'page', opening in maximized state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, wpf-controls

I am working with wpf page control. Here I need to start application and open page in maximized state.
For window control it is quite easy by setting the state and position, but using page control it is bit tricky.

Below xaml of the first page which is startupuri.

```
<Page x:Class="MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

        Title="MainWindow" ShowsNavigationUI="False"  Background="#ffffff">
```

I am able to height and widht as maximum size using below code:

```
this.WindowHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;

this.WindowWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
```

But screens opens at default location with screen overshooting the monitor visual area.
Need some help regarding this issue. thanks

Comment: can't you just maximize the size of the parent windows(where the frame is used)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joseph, i missed that part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the page's parent `Window` to maximized state in the page's `Loaded` event handler, something like:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     (this.Parent as Window).WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```